# 3D globe on QGIS 3D view

Tags: qgis, 3d, globe

I am using QGIS 3.22. Is there a way to load a 3D globe model into the 3d view in QGIS so I can turn it around and etc. like Google Earth? If it possible where can I find or how do I create something like that?